# Passing an instance of Class to Class constructor

Tags: python, class, constructor, software-design

I have a class `Person` like this:

```py
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

print(Person("George").name)
# prints 'George'
```

I would like to make it so that even if I pass a `Person` object to `name`, the instantiated object ignores the constructor and returns the passed `Person` object, for example:

```py
p1 = Person("George")
p2 = Person(p1) # this should behave as p2 = p1

print(p2.name)
# should print 'George'
```

I can't do it in `__init__`, as it cannot return anything:

```py
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        if isinstance(name, type(self)):
            return name # TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'Person'
        self.name = name
```

Therefore I'm trying to do it with `__new__`:

```py
class Person(object):
    def __new__(cls, name):
        if isinstance(name, cls):
            return name
        return super().__new__(cls)
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

But I'm doing something wrong as it seems to call `__init__` after I return `name`:

```py
p1 = Person("Tom")
p2 = Person(p1)

print(p2.name)
# prints '<__main__.Person object at 0x000002C029C54490>'
```

I'm guessing this has to do with the fact that by default, `__new__` will call `__init__` if an instance of `cls` has been returned, which is what's happening in this case.

**How could I make it so that when I pass an instance as parameter to the class constructor, the constructor returns the instance?**

*I'm open to different design suggestions if this is not the best way to approach the issue, although I'd like to learn how to do this, as it seems pretty convenient*.

EDIT: In order to avoid the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), I'll add some information on *why* I'm trying to do this: in a nutshell, I'm trying to make sure that certain parameters (in different parts of the codebase) always are instances of the same class (in this case, Person), but I wanted to avoid type checking all of these variables. I realize a factory approach would make more sense, but I thought the class-constructor-returning-the-instance approach was kinda neat.

Comment: Instead of `return name`, you should do `self.name = name.name`, because now `name` argumet to `__init__` is instance of class Person and you want the instance you create to use the argument's name attribute. That said this doesn't make much sense, it smells like XY problem and probably you are trying to do some sort of inheritance here.

Comment: I thought about that, but it's a bit burdensome if I have plenty of attributes. I was looking for a more general, flexible solution. Regarding the XY problem, I'll edit my question with some more details about the root problem

Comment: It does sound like the class is trying to be too clever for its own good. The standard constructor should behave in a simple and predictable fashion. If it makes sense for your typical use case to have a helper that can return a new instance or use the existing instance, it should be a separate helper, like a `classmethod`: `Person.maybe_new(p1)`.

Comment: @deceze Yes, that's actually very neat. I might do it this way. Is it bad practice to try to squeeze all of this logic into the standard constructor (to save a few characters)?

Comment: It still sounds like an XY problem. You should *know* what types your variables are without needing to check and conditionally branch. If you don't know what your types are at all times, your dataflow is foobar'd. Either way, it's a problem external to the class; the class shouldn't have to worry about or compensate for logic problems the code using it has.

Comment: I'd actually start with strictly typing the constructor: `def __init__(self, name: str)`, and _perhaps_ even an `assert isinstance(name, str)`, and then trace backwards to find all the cases where it's *not* a string and figure out why and fix that.

Comment: I do know what type my variables are, but I want to give myself the option to throw different datatypes in the constructor so I don't have to type check to re-instantiate the object everytime. I'm actually taking inspiration from Pandas, where you can, for example , instantiate `t = pd.Timestamp("2022-1-1")` which returns an instance of `pd.Timestamp` and you can also do `t1 = pd.Timestamp(t)` and that will return a new instance of `pd.Timestamp` with the same attributes as `t` (as far as I can tell)

Comment: That's quite a difference. What you're trying to do is *pass through the existing instance*. That's different from *copying* an instance. The latter one indeed makes sense in many cases, e.g. `list(lst)` can make perfect sense to explicitly create a copy. To do that, something like `return cls(arg[0])` in `__new__` or something similar in `__init__` makes sense.

Comment: I hear you. I thought passing through the instance would make sense in terms of saving resources (why copying everything over when you can just return the instance) but maybe it's not the best approach. Could you code up your idea?